# Am I thinking about whole company returns correct?

Tags: stocks, value-investing

I'm trying to answer the questions: "if I owned all of a company, how much would I make?" and "once I know that, how much should I pay?"

Let's say I owned Wal-mart outright (took it private and owned 100% of the company).  I'm not paying off all its debts so we'll leave interest expense, etc. the same.  For this discussion, ignore any minority interest.  I believe I would earn:

- all of the net earnings.  That's after taxes, after interest, after capex - the Net Income on the income statement.  For 2018, that was $10,523 billion.
- all of the dividends.  From 2018's Cash Flow Statement, that puts another $6,124 billion in my pocket.
- all of the share buyback money.  Again from the 2018 CFS, that's another $8,296 billion I get.

Adding these three, Wal-mart throws off about $24,943 billion per year.  I say "throws off" in the accounting sense, not the free cash flow sense.

If I spent $100bn to buy Wal-mart, I'd earn about 25% annual return.  If I spent $400bn, it'd be only a 6% return.  I'd want my return to at least equal an index fund, and perhaps a bit more since it's riskier, so 10-15% return would mean I'd value Wal-mart at maybe $150-250bn.

Obviously, I'm ignoring future growth prospects, which greatly complicates the math, but let's pretend for a moment that Wal-mart is going to perform exactly as it did in 2018 for the foreseeable future.  With that assumption, am I thinking about these numbers correctly?

Comment: Aren’t dividends paid out of net earnings? I’m not sure you should be adding these together. (Same for stock buyback.)

Comment: For clarity, the commas are used as decimal points here ($25 billion not $25000 billion).

Comment: @nanoman: For clarity, while comma as a decimal point is a fairly widespread convention, with quantities denominated in US Dollars the convention is to use a dot.

Comment: If you owned all *shares* of walmart, how will a *share* buyback affect you ? Do you just pay yourself for a share that you then give yourself ?

Comment: @xyious The money they spent during the year in question on buy-backs (presumably) doesn't show up in that year's net earnings (it will have been an expense). Under the OP's assumption-for-the-sake-of-argument that WalMart will perform the same in the next year as this, then _next_ year, the amount they set aside to buy shares will increase next year's earnings.

Comment: My point was just that this whole question is double counting income. Walmart made $10 Billion, then paid dividends out of that and share buybacks as well. Now again, if you own all shares, then the company buys back shares, you're paying yourself for a share you give your company.... essentially yourself. It doesn't make sense and it doesn't create money. Otherwise you could just issue a million new shares every year to existing shareholders and then buy them back and you create billions of dollars every year.

Answer (score 2):

The return you are calculating is the earnings yield, the inverse of the P/E ratio. If you assume that "Wal-mart is going to perform exactly as it did in 2018 for the foreseeable future", then you would value the company like a low-risk long-term bond. Returns on those are under 5% these days. The long-term return on stocks (or stock index funds) is higher because of earnings *growth*. That is the main factor in their valuation, and also contributes substantial *risk*. While delivering their typical 10% *total return*, stocks rarely get cheap enough to buy at a 10% *earnings yield*.